# Can wpf apps use cache stored in the asp.net web server?

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, caching, iis

We have client side applications written in WPF which are making requests to the server side MVC web app each time.

Since they sometimes are requesting with the same parameters. We want the server side to cache the result.

If one client requests once, another client will use the cache data in the server. But it seems that the client apps are not using the cache data. The second client app will still call the function in the server.

How can we let client side to use cache on the server side?

Comment: If your server is not using the cache, there is something broken in that implementation. A client cannot and should not use a server side cache.

Comment: Thanks ryadavilli, I mean can server side detect it is using the same parameter with the last request and return the cached data to the client?

Comment: You will need to build that logic in. Can you explain what is the server side caching that you are using ?

Comment: Thanks, I am using asp mvc output cache:

Comment: [OutputCache(Duration = 840, VaryByParam = "*")] by default it will cache on the server, client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net 4 can use MemoryCache. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net-4-0) should get you started.